# flutter branch IO integration and attribution implement

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, branch.io, attribution

I am using [flutter_branch_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_branch_sdk) package to integrate branch IO SDK

I am trying to track the user install attribution, where user coming from such as user coming from twitter, Instagram, and such a xyz website

flutter version:

Flutter 1.22.5
channel stable
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework
revision 7891006299
(6 weeks ago) • 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800 Engine
• revision ae90085a84
Tools • Dart 2.10.4

inside init method I check the FlutterBranchSdk.validateSDKIntegration(); and it through the error

**output**

```
D/BranchSDK_Doctor( 8544):
D/BranchSDK_Doctor( 8544): ------------------- Initiating Branch integration verification --------------------------- ...
D/BranchSDK_Doctor( 8544): 1. Verifying Branch instance creation ...
D/BranchSDK_Doctor( 8544): Passed
D/BranchSDK_Doctor( 8544): 2. Checking Branch keys ...
D/BranchSDK_Doctor( 8544): Passed
I/BranchSDK( 8544): getting https://api2.branch.io/v1/app-link-settings/key_test_pp6bmR0ECJa5GS3?metadata
I/BranchSDK( 8544): returned {"android_uri_scheme":"https://companyname.com://","android_package_name":"com.abc.name.app","short_url_domain":"","default_short_url_domain":"abc.test-app.link","alternate_short_url_domain":" test link change for security purpose","ios_uri_scheme":"iOS url","ios_team_id":"iOS_team id","ios_bundle_id":"id"}
D/BranchSDK_Doctor( 8544): 3. Verifying application package name ...
D/BranchSDK_Doctor( 8544): ** ERROR ** : Incorrect package name in Branch dashboard. Please correct your package name in dashboard -> link Settings page.
D/BranchSDK_Doctor( 8544): Please follow the link for more info https://docs.branch.io/pages/dashboard/integrate/#android
```

PS: some above information change for security purpose but I check several time my package name is correct

for the last two days I am stick on this topic

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you recheck if you are using the API keys correctly? If you are using the Test API key, make sure you entered the package name in the Test Environment of Branch Dashboard.

Comment: UPDATE: I solve this issue the problem is that I mistakenly put the test key in the production mode

Answer (score 1):

For Future Reference:

In case you observe a similar issue where the Integration Validator returns an error of `incorrect package name`, ensure that you are using the API keys as per the set Dashboard configuration.

If `testMode` is set to true, you'd need to configure your application details in the TestMode of the Branch Dashboard and vice versa.